# ConstraintLayout 2.0.4 layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle have a problem

Tags: android

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
                 <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_person_info_sex_man"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_age"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_uid" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_age"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_person_info_age_school_region"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/c_397DF0"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_region"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        tools:text="@string/tip_common_error" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_region"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_person_info_age_school_region"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/c_397DF0"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_school"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_age"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        tools:text="@string/tip_common_error" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_school"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_person_info_age_school_region"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingStart="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/c_397DF0"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_info_more"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_region"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        tools:text="@string/tip_common_error" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_info_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_person_info_more"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_person_info_fragment_user_school"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_person_info_fragment_user_sex" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is kotlin code

tv_person_info_fragment_user_age.text = "21"

tv_person_info_fragment_user_region.text = "BeiJing"

first picture is editor preview

[image]

second picture is phone preview

[image]

Can you help me ,this is why?  the textview is not show content,when i set textView minWidth 50dp the textView will show 50dp width

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem exactly like you did. Downgrade to version `1.1.3` solve the problem.

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: yes,i know, but i want know this is why?this is 2.x issure?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it is.